# Particle usage of は and が in this sentence

Tags: meaning, particles, particle-は, particle-が

I had some particle trouble translating these lines:

> 四月の魚は風が吹いて

> 長い髪が揺れている

The first two lines seem to go together in one sentence, but then there would be too many particles. I have it as "The April fish is blown by the wind, long hair swaying" but I don't think the "*by* the wind" is supported by the text. Is this correct? Whether it's correct or not, could someone please explain how the particles all work together?

The lines are from the song [April Story](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/31606.html), but they flash by in the music video and so are not sung; neither are they contained in the lyrics. For context, the line before is "If I died, I'd want to die in a small water tank," and after is "Spring came to us." (I'm having trouble typing Japanese on my computer, or I would type them out).

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I don't see any lines like Spring has come to us in the lyrics. Couldn't you have just written the romaji instead of giving your own translation? But I can't view the video anyway because I don't have a nico account. :/

Edit: ok so I googled the lines and it seems you linked the wrong song and title. The song is 四月の魚. So, 四月の魚は as for the April Fish, 風が吹いて 長い髪が揺れている the long hair is being blown by the wind. て has a meaning like で, "by means of".

Comment: No, I am translating April Story. As I wrote in the original post, these lines just flash by on the music video, and are not contained in the actual lyrics. But I guess those lines must be a reference to Mer's other work 四月の魚. For some reason typing romaji didn't occur to me (lol). Anyways, thanks for the help!

Comment: This... this is not an answer